# Why Form Elements should not be named submit?

Tags: javascript

I figured out through debugging that I should not name any Form Elements `name="submit"`, but even after searching I didn't find any good explanation of why?

See simple code example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="javascript:alert('submitted');" method="post" id="test-form">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name-field" value="" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Button" /> <!-- name should not be "submit" -->
            <p><a href="javascript: document.getElementById('test-form').submit();">Submit Link</a></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

- If you **Press Enter** while on any Form Element or **Click** the
  *Submit Button*, it will work.
- If you **Click** on the *Submit Link*, it will have error

  Unhandled Error: 'document.getElementById('test-form').submit' is not a function

If you simply **rename** your *Submit Button* to anything other than `name="submit"` (even if you just capitalize some part of it) or just **remove** the `name="submit"` attribute, then both the *Submit Button* and *Submit Link* will work.

I tried this in the latest version of Internet Explorer, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari. All of them have consistent behavior with regards to this.

As you can see in my code example, there is no involvement of jQuery or any other JavaScript library.

I would appreciate the explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the Mozilla docs here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLFormElement

You will see that forms have a `.submit()` method.

In addition, forms are also populated with the fields within the form.

(Here is one example:
  http://www.devbay.com/articles/javascript/accessing-form-elements-array-with-javascript/
  I can't find any reference that it *should* happen, only that it does.)

So, when you make an element called `submit` it over-rides the forms built-in `submit()` method -- and since the element is, well, *not* a function, you get that error message.

Comment: It makes sense now. So best practice would be to avoid all Form methods in any of the Form Element names. Thanks

Comment: "Best Practice" is hard to define at times, but it is safe to say that you shouldn't run into trouble if you do follow that rule of thumb.

Answer (score 2):

Say your form is named `"foo"` and you have a field `"firstName"`.

`foo.firstName` is that field in the form.

`foo.submit()` will submit that form, because `submit` is a method on forms.

If you redefine `submit` to be a form field you overwrite the `submit` method.

Comment: That makes complete sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

submit would be the form input type and i think is also used as an identifier in javascript. So naming a submit button "submit" makes the use of "submit" in javascript ambiguous