# php - my form isn't validating

Tags: php, validation

http://patti-bee2.dcccd.edu/coleman/wonder%20penguin/php/register.php

Here's how the form is supposed to work--- It's supposed to use sticky tags for people who have not visited the site before and give it some default values. And when you submit the form, it's supposed to validate on the page and refresh if there is a problem and if everything is correct it's supposed to redirect you to another page with the results. (The part I don't need to put on there because I'm 100% it's not the problem.)

What do you think what's wrong? I made it close to my teacher's code.

All mine does when you submit the code is that my page just blinks then goes back.

```
<?php


ob_start();
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $valid = true;
    $validate = true;

    $username = trim($_REQUEST['username']);
    $email = trim($_REQUEST['email']);
    $password = trim($_REQUEST['password']);
}
else
{ 
    $username = "";
    $email = "";
    $password = "";
    $valid = false;
    $validate = false;
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="register.php">
<label for="username"> Username </label><input type="text" name="username" id="username"
 value="<?php echo $username ?>">
<?php   if ($validate) {
    if (empty($username)) { 
        echo "<p> There must be a username! </p>";
        $valid = false;
        }
    if (strlen($username) > 15) { 
        echo "<p> This username is too long! It must be 8-15 characters long! </p>";
        $valid = false;
    }
    if (strlen($username) < 8) {
        echo "<p> This username is too short! It must be 8-15 characters long! </p>";
        $valid = false;
    }
    } 
    ?>
<label for="email">E-Mail </label><input type="email" name="email" id="email"
 value="<?php echo $email ?>">
<?php  if ($validate) {
    if (empty($email)) {
        echo "<p> We need an email! </p>";
        $valid = false;
    }
}
?>
<label for="password">Password </label><input type="text" name="password" id="password" 
value="<?php echo $password ?>">
<?php if ($validate) {
    if (empty($password)) {
        echo "<p> We need a password! </p>";
        $valid = false;
    }
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="Register!" />
</form>
<?php
    if ($valid) { 
        require_once 'config/connection.php';

        $query = "INSERT INTO user (username, email, password) values ( $username, $email, $password);";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $dbConn);     
        if ($result) {
            $userid = mysql_insert_id();        
            header("Location:success.php?userid=$userid");
            ob_end_clean();
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "<p> Unable to Update Database! </p>";
        }
    }
    ob_end_flush();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look and see what's in `mysql_error` - I expect the issue is because you need to quote the values you're passing in. But be warned - mysql_* is deprecated, and your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should look at moving to mysqli_ or PDO instead, as they both make it easier for you to write safer code.

Comment: Andrew-- I am a noob when it comes to PHP, so I haven't gotten into security yet. But thank you.

Comment: @Lalien-MilesLamarColeman SQL injection problems aren't just about security... escaping data for use in a query is required if you expect it to work properly.  Otherwise, you will spend quite a bit of time tracking down problems every time you need an apostrophe or quote mark or something.  Also, if you are learning database programming without prepared/parameterized queries, you are learning incorrectly.  This isn't something you progress to... what you are being taught is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your submit button does not have a `name` attribute, so `isset($_POST['submit'])` is never true.

Try giving your submit button `name="submitted"` and check for `isset($_POST['submitted'])`.

### Edit:

See this post regarding why naming submit buttons "submit" is not recommended:
[Why Form Elements should not be named submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272123/why-form-elements-should-not-be-named-submit)

> "...when you make an element called submit it over-rides the forms
>   built-in submit() method..."

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have a success.php page, but you do have a /registersuccessful.php page

Change this:

```
if ($result) {
            $userid = mysql_insert_id();        
            header("Location:success.php?userid=$userid");
            ob_end_clean();
            exit();
```

to this

```
if ($result) {
            $userid = mysql_insert_id();        
            header("Location:registersuccessful.php?userid=$userid");
            ob_end_clean();
            exit();
```

Comment: Nice catch. How did you ever find the true name of that page?

Comment: Oh crap. I totally forgot to upload success.php! Thank you!

Comment: I have made progress, I went from getting nothing to getting an actual error that I set myself! This is great!

Comment: @showdev I visited the base directory. There were no redirects or permissions so anyone can view them.

Answer (score 0):

You check for $_POST['submit'], but this element is not being submitted. Add name='submit' to your submit button (or better, give it another name like btnSubmit and check for this in your _POST):

Comment: This does appear to be the source of the problem, but naming submit buttons "submit" is not recommended as it can conflict with other actions. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272123/why-form-elements-should-not-be-named-submit

Answer (score 0):

You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and also have SQL syntax errors. Even if the code actually did reach your INSERT query, the query will fail due to the errors:

```
    $query = "INSERT [...snip...] values ('$username', '$email', '$password');";
                                          ^--       ^--^--    ^--^--       ^--
```

None of your inserted values are quoted.

Comment: Still learning about security and whatnot. But this one really helped! It works now! I wish I could vote up all of you guys! But I'm not high enough! Thank you all!