# parsley form not submitting when submit button has name="submit"

Tags: javascript, forms, parsley.js

I just discovered that my form isn't submitting when i give the submit element the name="submit" attribute. When I change the the name to something else, it works perfectly!

I am using parsley.remote.min.js * Version 2.0.3 - built Mon Jul 21 2014 11:58:33

Sorry I cannot provide code right now, I just wanted to throw that out there. Is it possibly I am doing something wrong?

Comment: You should read this: [Why Form Elements should not be named submit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272123/why-form-elements-should-not-be-named-submit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you name a form element "submit", you inadvertently override the form's `submit` method with an input object. For example, with this:

```
<form id="testForm">
    <input type="text" name="testInput" />
</form>
```

You can now access the input element by name through a property on the form object:

```
var testInput = document.getElementById('testForm').testInput;
```

Forms have a `submit()` method you can call programmatically (which is the same one invoked by clicking a button or input of "submit" type):

```
document.getElementById('testForm').submit();
```

Perhaps now you can see the problem by naming a form element "submit" -- you're taking away the form's ability to be submitted because `submit()` no longer exists -- it's been redefined as a property that returns a reference to your submit button.

More explanation is available here:

- [Why Form Elements should not be named submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272123/why-form-elements-should-not-be-named-submit)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I thought parsley to be the problem! Funny that I've never encountered that in my 8 years of web programming :)

Comment: I think we as programmers tend to shy away from naming things with reserved keywords, so good on you for not encountering this before. Admittedly I've not thought of the implications of this in the DOM before today but it does make a lot of sense!