# Parsley.js remote validation response still validates to true after ParsleyUI.addError

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I have this form:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" data-parsley-validate>
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" required>
<input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" required>
<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" 
            data-parsley-trigger="focusout" 
            data-parsley-remote
            data-parsley-remote-options='{ "type": "POST" }'
            data-parsley-remote-validator='validateName'
            required>
<input type="button" id="formSave" name="submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

And script:

```
var userName = $('#userName').parsley();
var _xsrf = $("[name='_xsrf']").val();
$('#myForm').parsley()
    .addAsyncValidator('validateName', function(xhr) {
        window.ParsleyUI.removeError(userName, 'name-exists');
        if (xhr.status == '404') {
            window.ParsleyUI.addError(userName, 'name-exists', "Name already exists.");
            return 404;
        } else if (xhr.status == '200') {
            return 200;
        }
    }, '/validate/?country=' + country + '&_xsrf=' + _xsrf);
```

The error message is displayed correctly if user already exists, however the field is still validated as correct.

Doing this was so easy in v1 of Parsley.js : /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some changes to your html and js:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="_xsrf" id="_xsrf" value="test">
    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" 
            data-parsley-trigger="focusout"
            data-parsley-remote
            data-parsley-remote-options='{ "type": "POST" }'
            data-parsley-remote-validator="validateName"
            data-parsley-remote-message="Name already exists."
            required>
    <!--<input type="button" id="formSave" name="submit" value="Next">-->
    <input type="submit" id="formSave" name="formSave" value="Next">
</form>
```

It is not a good idea to set `submit` as the name of your button. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996452/parsley-form-not-submitting-when-submit-button-has-name-submit) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272123/why-form-elements-should-not-be-named-submit).

In your javascript, append the `addAsyncValidator` to your field instead of the form. As for the validator response, it has to return `true` of `false`. If you want your field to be valid when you get a `200` response, then you must use

```
return xhr.status === 200
```

If you assume that the field is valid when the status response is `404`, then you should use:

```
return xhr.status === 404
```

Here is the code that worked for me. If you use a valid URL that returns a `404` status code, the error will be displayed and the form will not be validated.

```
var _xsrf = $("#_xsrf").val();
var userName = $("#userName").parsley()
    .addAsyncValidator('validateName', function (xhr) {
         return xhr.status === 200;
    }, 'http://localhost/parsley/CheckEmailAvailability.php?_xsrf=' + _xsrf);

$( "#myForm" ).parsley();

$("#myForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    $(this).parsley("validate");
    if ($(this).parsley("isValid")) {
        console.log('valid');
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/ryQu5/1/) for the full code. Since you have to perform a server request, the form will never be validated (due to Access-Control-Allow-Origin). However, if you test this locally with a valid request, it will work.

Comment: This behaves the same way. The error shows up, but the entire form still validates. I'll edit my question to include other inputs in the form.

Comment: I have edited my answer and made some changes in your HTML and JS. I tested this and this worked ok.
Please let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: This still has the same behavior. I read [a github issue](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/636) where @guillaumepotier says "`ParsleyUI.addError()` only handles interface, not validation itself." Will need to use events like `parsley:form:validate`. But I'm still lost : /

Comment: I was assuming that you were validating the form. I have edited my answer in order to add the form submit event that validates the form. 
I have also added a jsfiddle, that will never submit the form due to cross origin request). However, if you execute the code locally and provide a valid URL, this should work.

Comment: Sir/Madam, you are amazing. Thank you so much. This worked wonderfully. I wish I could give you all the votes in the world. Apologies for not phrasing the problem correctly in the first place.