# Parsley remote replace default error message

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I want to show 'Name is already exists ' instead of 'This value seems to be invalid.' in parsley remote validation.

I tried using

```
$('#script-name').parsley()
    .addAsyncValidator('remotevalidator', function (xhr) { 
        var userName = $('#user-name').parsley(); 
        var valid = (xhr.responseText != 'true'); 

        if(valid){ 
            window.ParsleyUI.removeError(name,'remote'); 
        }else{ 
            window.ParsleyUI.addError(parsley,'remote','User name already used'); 
        } 

        return valid; 
    }, PageVariables.USER_NAME_EXISTS_URL);
```

but it gives both messages.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with your parsley js? Also, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049536/parsley-js-remote-validation-response-still-validates-to-true-after-parsleyui-ad/25049642#25049642) where you can check that same case.

Answer (score 6):

I will point out what you should change to make your code work, but there is a simpler way to accomplish what you want at the end of this answer.

```
<input type="text" name="userName" id="user-name"
    data-parsley-trigger="focusout"
    data-parsley-remote
    data-parsley-remote-options='{ "type": "POST" }'
    data-parsley-remote-validator="remotevalidator"
    required />

<script>
var username = $("#user-name").parsley()
    .addAsyncValidator('remotevalidator', function (xhr) {
        var valid = xhr.responseText != 'true';

        window.ParsleyUI.removeError(username,'remote');
        window.ParsleyUI.removeError(username,'remotevalidator');

        if( !valid ) {
            window.ParsleyUI.addError(username,'remotevalidator', 'User name already used');
        }

        return valid;

    }, PageVariables.USER_NAME_EXISTS_URL);
</script>
```

Some remarks:

1. In your code you are using `$('#script-name').parsley().addAsyncValidator(...)`. Note that you should add the async validator to the *field* not the *form*. So, you should use `$("#user-name")`
2. When you add or remove messages from `window.ParsleyUI`, you are refering to `username` and `parsley`. You should always refer to `username` defined at the beggining.
3. You will always want to remove the default message for `remote`, no matter the result of the validation. It is also important to remove any previous messages that I've called `remotevalidator`.

**There is a simpler way to accomplish what you want**

Instead of messing with `window.ParsleyUi`, you could just set the message in your input. Your code will look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="userName" id="user-name"
    data-parsley-trigger="focusout"
    data-parsley-remote
    data-parsley-remote-options='{ "type": "POST" }'
    data-parsley-remote-validator="remotevalidator"
    data-parsley-remote-message="User name already used"
    required />

<script>
var username = $("#user-name").parsley()
    .addAsyncValidator('remotevalidator', function (xhr) {
        return xhr.responseText != 'true';

    }, PageVariables.USER_NAME_EXISTS_URL);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem adding a property "errorMessage" in element. Such as:

```
$("#user-name").parsley({ errorMessage: "User name already used" });
```